# Why can't my app link to my website from within the Android app

Tags: android, url

I have an Android app for which I must have a link to a website for my privacy policy.  I have recently created my own website with a page for the privacy policy of my app.  I want to be able to link to that page from within my app. I have it working fine using a link to a government website but when I use the link to my own website it doesn't work. I get the following error inside my app screen.

```
Webpage not available
The webpage at http://retirementcalculatoraustralia.com/privacy-policy.php could not be loaded because:
net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED
```

Here is the code in my fragment.

```
public class PrivacyPolicyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_privacy_policy, container, false);
        WebView webview = root.findViewById(R.id.privacy_policy_text);
        String url = "http://retirementcalculatoraustralia.com/privacy-policy.php";

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                String e = error.toString();
                System.out.println("ERROR " + e);
               // handler.proceed() ;
                handler.cancel();
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl(url);

        return root;
    }
}
```

I have typed the link into my browser to ensure it does exist and work. If I use the following government website link then it works fine.

```
String url = "https://www.servicesaustralia.gov.au/individuals/topics/deeming/29656";
```

If I remove the prefix http:// from my website link then I don't get the error but just get a blank screen. If I make the prefix http://www then I get the error. I made a change in my AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
  <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ......
```

and created the following file called network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">retirementcalculatoraustralia.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

None of this made any difference.  My website was published 1 to 2 days ago and is working fine if I type retirementcalculatoraustralia.com into my browser but not working from my app. The print statement in my fragment onReceivedSslError() never gets reached.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I am using API 30 with minimum 23. I think I find the answer and will post an answer to my question in case it is helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem after reading the information at the following link:
https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2018/08/15/a-security-analysts-guide-to-network-security-configuration-in-android-p/

I needed to fully understand the difference between HTTP and HTTPS and why this error was occurring.  I will summarise for others:

Cleartext is any transmitted or stored information that is not encrypted or meant to be encrypted.  When an app communicates with servers using a cleartext network traffic, such as HTTP, it could raise a risk of eavesdropping and tampering of content.
HTTPS uses TLS(SSL) to encrypt normal HTTP requests and responses.  With HTTP any login info, or personal information like credit card numbers could be stolen, read or modified by hackers.

Android 7.0 Nougat introduced the Android Network Security Configuration feature, which allows developers to be more prescriptive about secure communications. It is an XML file in which developers customize network security settings for an Android app.  It provides a layer to protect apps from unintentionally transmitting sensitive data in unencrypted cleartext.
In Android 9, cleartextTrafficPermitted is set to false by default.  This means if this flag is not explicitly set to false and the app is targeting API levels lower than 28, the flag will be honoured as true.
You can set cleartextTrafficPermitted to true on specific domains in network_security_config.xml.

The reason I was getting the error net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED when I tried to link to my website using http:// was because cleartextTrafficPermitted was set to false by default.  It worked fine when I tested it with a government website using https::// because this was a secure website using encryption.
Android comes with a set of preloaded CA (Certification Authority) root certificates trusted by the system.

For the solution to my problem I added the following to the AndroidManifest file,removing the line android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

In network_security_config.xml

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">insecure.example.com</domain>
       <trust-anchors>
         <certificates src="system"/>
       </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>
```

This tells Android that cleartext is only to be permitted from my own domain and trusted system certificates while the base config is set to false for everything else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My original answer has now been updated to clearly describe the problem and solution.